Is malicious design the next level up from deceptive design?
There has been some slight changes to the terminology used in describing some of the unethical practices by companies that impact on the user experience, often to the detriment of the consumer or end-user.
Recently there was a lot of publicity generated about the practice of one company when it came to the area of affiliate marketing. Regardless of the veracity of the accusations and investigations, it made me wonder if 'deceptive pattern' is an adequate description of these types of hostile and malicious practices.
So if dark patterns, which was the umbrella term for a lot of these 'bad design practices' has been changed to 'deceptive patterns', and if some of these seemingly deceptive tactics end up being exposed as outright malicious decisions and actions, should there be another term used for it instead?
Is there already an emerging or established term used for design with planned/intentional malicious or hostile actions that may or may not be obvious to the parties that are being effected like 'malicious patterns' or 'hostile patterns'?
